# Ruby: Find the item in an array that matches a condition, but raise error if there is not exactly one element that matches the condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, validation

A pattern I have found myself implementing a couple of times recently is along the lines of:

```
def request_from_transaction(array_of_messages) 
  request_array = array_of_messages.select { |msg| msg.is_request? } 
  raise MyExceptions::NotOneRequestError('The system expects only 1 request') unless request_array.size == 1

  request_array[0]
end
```

Because I have come across this several times recently, I wonder if this is a common pattern, and if so, is there is an idiomatic, elegant way to encode this behaviour in ruby without the conditional and explicit raise.

Preferably just using the ruby standard library in one line of code.

I am aware of:

```
array_of_messages.find { |msg| msg.is_request? }
```

But this will return the *first* message in the array that matches the criteria, if somehow there were actually 2 requests in the array, this will fail silently. The working assumption is that there is only one item in the array that matches, so I'd like to know if that assumption is incorrect.

I'm hoping that something along the lines of this exists:

```
array_of_messages.find_one_or_raise { |msg| msg.is_request? }
```

This doesn't exist in the standard library as far as I know.

The desired behaviour of such a method is:

```
[request, response, update, update].find_one_or_raise { |msg| msg.is_request? } 
# => request
```

and

```
[request, response, request, update].find_one_or_raise { |msg| msg.is_request? } 
# => exception raised 'found more than one item that matched'
```

and

```
[response, update, update].find_one_or_raise { |msg| msg.is_request? } 
# => exception raised 'found none that matched'
```

I think I could implement this myself and monkey patch a new method onto array or perhaps even enumerable if I gave it a bit of thought, but ideally I'm hoping there is already something out there.

Of course I could just carry of doing what I'm doing and repeating that same pattern...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: When you only expect one element with specific criteria in your list, then I wonder if a `Set` instead of an array would be a better data structure?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @spickermann, that's an interesting thought, there can be several updates, but they will be different updates so I think a set would work here.

Comment: And as pattern, the creation of the object (the array of messages) is probably the best place to do any checking required, rather than waiting until I need the request to find out there is more than one of them.

Comment: One thing here that tands out to me is `raise('The system expects only 1 request')`. This will raise a generic error which makes it very difficult to rescue the exception without being far to liberal about what you're rescuing and it also makes debugging harder. Be more specific.

Comment: Very good point @max. I was trying to keep the code sample as simple as possible, but absolutely, raising a specific exception class would be the correct thing to do somebody was implementing this in a real project. I'll edit the question if I can work out how to.

Comment: Question edited to add a custom exception class to the sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 7 introduced [Enumerable#sole](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sole) which kind of does what you want. It does not accept a block though so you would still have to do the select separately. It does nicely encapsulate the error raising, so might still be useful

```
array_of_messages.select(&:is_request?).sole
```

Without Rails I the solution you have is close to the best you can get. Could be optimized a bit to stop iterating once the 2nd element is found.

Comment: Thanks, that is very close, and I wasn't aware of it. I think I already have ActiveSupport in my project although it's not a RoR project. And as you say, doing this does remove all the conditionals and explicit raises.